# Transform Python HTML Inputs

Tags: python, cgi

I am writing a Python CGI that gets certain field values from a HTML page, I am at a point where I need to transform those input values to make them match table values of a database and get data from it.

For example, if the field value of my UI is 'critic' then it should be transformed to '8_critic' to match the database table value.

How can I do this please ?
Something like this maybe ?

```
 #!C:\Python27\python.exe -u
import cgi
import json
import cgitb
print "Content-type: application/json\n\n"

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()
def transform(fs):
 for key in fs.keys():
  if key == 'critic' :
    #key = '8_critic'
  elif key == 'somthing_else' :
    #key = 'another_thing'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"? Do you want to change some value in a database? Do you want to return a changed value in the HTTP response?

Comment: No, I want to transform the input value of the Python cgi then add that input to a parameterized query. Because the UI fields are not the same as the database column names or values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for me would me to have a translation table:

```
tr = { 'critic' : '8_critic', 'foo' : 'bar' }
```

and to make a new dictionnary by comprehension:

```
nfs = { tr[k]:fs[k] for k in fs }
```

Here, I assumed that you did not care about the FieldStorage at this point. If it isn't so, you can still do something like that:

```
nfs = cgi.FieldStorage()
for k in fs:
  nfs[ tr[k] ] = fs[k]
```

Comment: oh yes sorry, thank you I will test this and see how it works.